# How to model tables with RLS in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular, row-level-security

I am not sure how to model this.

I have 3 tables.

- Fact
- Contract
- Clients

[image]

[image]

Fact:

[image]

Then, the access with RLS will be based on contract. If you are manager1 or manager2 for that contract you shall see it (also if you are c. manager1  on that row you shall see it too).

So, for the table for access,  I will do an Unpivot like:

SqlTable

[image]

I have tried this model but it doesnt work:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easy using RLS always try to create a simple "data entitlement" table with one column for the key value of the table you're trying to filter, and one column for the user id, here

```
ContractId  UserId
    1        Peter
    1        Rob
    2        Peter
    2        Tim
    . . .
```

Then set your RLS Dax filter on this table's UserId table using USERPRINCIPALNAME, and make sure it has a relationship that flows filters to the target table.

Comment: But this means that the granularity is Contract... and I wouldn't be able to split contract by client, right?

Comment: Right.  But you can have a separate table for RLS on Client.